# openssl upgrade and apache 2.0

Tags: windows, openssl, apache2

I need to upgrade open ssl on a server that is running apache 2.0. I have found various fixes that talk about replacing libeay32, openssl.exe and ssleay32 but when I restart apache I get an error. Does the new version of openssl work with this version of apache? Is there a simple way to upgrade the open ssl?

The apache software installed with a version of vtiger crm and upgrading it doesn't seem very straight forward.

Comment: How did you install it? Did you use apt-get, yum ect or manually install?

Comment: Aapache? It came bundeled in a vtiger crm exe. The openssl ddls I just copied them into the apache bin folder. I tried to install apache 2.4 by placing the pache 2.4 folder at the same leal s the previous, copy the httdoc and conf files from the old apache to the new. The Operating system is Windows

Comment: is this on windows or linux? ah you ust updated it

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: from the apache service monitor just a'the requested operation has failed'

Comment: Ok, think I must have been using the wrong ddl. I downloaded from here: http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html, installed openssl then got the files from the bin folder it creates and apache started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem related, I think, to the need to make sure you're using the windows DDLs. I installed openssl from here: http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html. Go into the files it creates and find the three files I mentioned in the question from the bin folder and copy these into your apache bin instead and worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

So, OpenSSL binaries were distributed freely on the openssl.org site in 2014?  Now (October 2016) we have incomplete wads of sources you can attempt to build until you give up.  Downgrading to Visual Studio 6.0 will not fix the fact that httpd-2.4.23 and openssl-1.1.0b are a travesty of source management.  You cannot build what does not exist.

I am not a representative of either of these projects, but I highly recommend avoiding the lies of Win32 compiling and visit these two sites: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html  and http://www.apachelounge.com/download/